# Asset image not showing up correctly

Tags: ios, swift, icons, assets

I was working with some asset icons and I realized that one of my icons didn't come out correctly

[image]

The right caret in the storyboard appears correctly but in multiple simulators it doesn't show up right. I've tried different content modes but no help. I don't think it is a constraint problem because I've tried a couple of placements and different icons but only the caret one doesn't look right. All the icons I have been using are the same px and using the same scale, single scale. Why is my icon acting up? All my asset icons are in PDF which has worked in the past and has not been a problem until now

Caret picture
[image: This is the caret file]

Comment: Have you tested in actual device? Simulators may not correct at times

Comment: Add your "icon" image file to your post... someone else here can see if it happens with that file to them.

Comment: @DonMag what is the best way to do that?

Comment: @LampPost - the same way you added your screen-cap image.

Comment: @AustinMichael yeah I tried it but it's the same. Nothing shows up on my iPhone SE

Comment: @LampPost - sorry, I wasn't clear... post the actual `icon_right-caret.png` file.

Comment: @DonMag ah alright. I left an edit saying that all my icons that I have been user are in `PDF` format and haven't had a problem since using it so I don't know if that is causing the problem

Comment: OK - if that's the only one giving you trouble, it sounds like this particular pdf may have a mis-matched "page size" ... Try re-creating the pdf maybe?

Comment: Yeah it worked after I remade the image. I'm guessing it is because turning the original PDF 180 degrees doesn't work. Ha...